# Invoke init method of second component from first in lightning:tabset

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In parent component, I have lightning:TabSet tag. In this tag I have child component name 'createTab' and in its JS controller I am creating three child component using $A.createComponent method that will correspond to three tabs.

My requirement is when I am on second tab, I select some record -> click on button and save selected record to DB. 
When I click on third tab, I want to get the records that I selected in second tab. (Third tab only show record when I refresh the page). But I want that when I select record on second tab, click button and navigate to third tab, it should show the latest record selected without hitting refresh.

In init method of third component js file, I am getting record. So I just want to inovke the init method of third component when third tab is clicked. But init is not invoked becasue component are already loaded in start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the change event instead of instead if init.
<aura:handler name = "change" value = "{!v.ListhavingnewData}" action = "{!c.doInit}"/>

Comment: Maybe you want to use aura:methods as opposed to the initialisation event.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_method.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
<lightning:tab label="Item One" id="one" onactive="{!c.activeHnadler}">
</lightning:tab>
```

You can add a onactive handler to tab. Whenever inactive handler is called 
, you can find id of tab using `event.getSource().get('v.id');` and then use aura method on you child component to start init logic.

Comment: If you can post your code we can be able to give detailed solution of your problem.